# Defining Nodes. Adjust Regex to exclude certain nodes

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am making node definitions in puppet. Need little help with regex. Currently this is what I am using

```
node /^[d][e][v]-\d{6}-[0-9][1-9][a|b].test-cloud.prod.puppet$/
```

I want puppet not to run its catalog with this cert having the `01a` or `01b`. Like the example shown below.

(I don't want Puppet to run on the machines having these certs)

`dev-123456-01a.test-cloud.prod.puppet` 
`dev-999999-01b.test-cloud.prod.puppet`
`dev-000001-01a.test-cloud.prod.puppet`

(Puppet needs to runs on the machines having these certs)

`dev-123456-02a.test-cloud.prod.puppet` 
`dev-999999-11b.test-cloud.prod.puppet`
`dev-000001-03a.test-cloud.prod.puppet`

I hope my explanation is clear now. Probably there is a simple solution to this but can't figure out.

Comment: Does the regex need to exclude the combinations `01a` and `01b` explicitly? Or is the intent to exclude everything that is followed by a letter (`01c`, `04z`, `10a`)? Could you provide a scenario that is not excluded? Are `dev-123456-01c.test-cloud.prod.puppet` and `ev-123456-01.test-cloud.prod.puppet` valid for example?

Comment: It is the first case where I only need to exclude 01a or 01b.

Comment: When addressing questions that seek to clarify the question it is always best to edit your answer, rather than elaborating in comments. For one, not all readers read all comments. Questions should be self-contained. Additional examples would be helpful here. Please show the desired return value for each. "Exclude" is not clear.

Comment: I have updated my question and hope it is clear now.

Comment: Note that `"de|f".match?(/[a|b]/) #=> true`. You want `[ab]` or `(?:a|b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
/^dev-\d{6}-(?!01[ab])[0-9][1-9][a-z]\.test-cloud\.prod\.puppet$/
```

[image: regex graph]

This still allows the generic regex `[0-9][1-9][a-z]` but exludes `01a` and `01b` up front (with `(?!01[ab])`). Reason for this is to keep the regex relatively clean. The alternative is something like `(01[c-z]|(0[2-9]|[1-9][1-9])[a-z])` instead of `(?!01[ab])[0-9][1-9][a-z]` which is a lot harder to maintain.

Note that `[0-9][1-9]` does exclude `00` (which I believe is your intention), but also excludes `20`, `30`, ... `90` which might not be your intention.

Comment: I'm not sure what letters are allowed. If only `a` and `b` are allowed simply replace `[a-z]` with `[ab]`.

Comment: Good answer. Would you take $50 for the artwork? How did you produce that? (It doesn't look like a regex site.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland https://regexper.com/ exported a SVG and uploaded it to https://svgshare.com since SO doesn't allow SVG uploads.

Comment: I noticed that you can alternatively download files from regexper.com in ".png" format. Those files can be uploaded directly to SO.

Comment: I know, but I prefer the ".svg" format since it's rendered on the client machine and therefore should be sharper and scale better with 4k screens. This does bring the risk of the URL eventually being broken, but if/when that happens I can always generate a ".png" and upload it to SO directly.

Comment: First of all thank you  3limin4t0r for giving such a detailed answer. Your solution is close but as you rightly said my intention was to exclude '00' but not to exclude 20,30,40 etc. In our environment for the time being the machine nomenclature will only include 'a' or 'b' would be used . So I believe [ab] would suffice.

Comment: @tafz `(?!00|01[ab])\d{2}[ab]` would then meet the requirements. Which excludes `00`, `01a` and `01b`. This replaces the following part of the regex `(?!01[ab])[0-9][1-9][a-z]`

Comment: Ah yes! . Thanks